Swagger UI and OpenAPI 3 - Switch request body examples by example $ref
I have 2 schemas with an example. I want to change the request body with the dropdown.
Actually everything is working. I have the list with examples displayed and the values in RequestBody change only if I write them as "value".
If I specify examples as ref, the first example is loaded, but the second example is not shown when the value in the dropdown list changes.
Is this just not implemented, is this a bug or have I done something/configured something wrong?
Screenshot:

And Config examples:
"requestBody": {
  "content": {
    "application/json": {
      "schema": {
        "oneOf": [
          {"$ref": "#/components/schemas/reportexample1"},
          {"$ref": "#/components/schemas/reportexample2"}
        ]
      },
      "examples": {
        "reportexample1": {
          "summary": "reportexample1",
          "$ref": "#/components/schemas/reportexample1"
        },
        "reportexample2": {
          "summary": "reportexample2",
          "$ref": "#/components/schemas/reportexample2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
},

......
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "reportexample1": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": { .... }
      },
      "reportexample2": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": { .... }
      }
    }
  }


To use $ref in examples, the references examples must be defined in the components/examples section and use the Example Object syntax.
examples cannot reference schemas (#/components/schemas/...) - this is why your original snippet does not work.
Try this:
      "examples": {
        "reportexample1": {
          "$ref": "#/components/examples/reportexample1"
        },
        "reportexample2": {
          "$ref": "#/components/examples/reportexample2"
        }
      }
      ...

  "components": {
    "examples": {
      "reportexample1": {
        "summary": "Example of reportexample1",
        "value": {
          "prop1": "value1",
          "prop2": 123
        }
      },
      "reportexample2": {
        "summary": "Example of reportexample2",
        "value": {
          "prop3": true,
          "prop4": [5, 6, 7]
        }
      }
    }
  }

The inline example approach suggested in Artur May's answer will also work.

Thanks @Helen ! It works as it was expected to. I should have defined the examples in the "examples" section, not in the "schemas".
Quick question. Are examples displayed in the Swagger UI the same way as Schemas (Bottom)? I don't see them.

"Are examples displayed in the Swagger UI the same way as Schemas (Bottom)?" - No, these examples are only displayed inside the operations that reference them and are accessed via dropdown selection.

Understood - thanks.

You can try to define the examples directly in the examples section instead of referencing them with $ref.
Something like this:
"requestBody": {
  "content": {
    "application/json": {
      "schema": {
        "oneOf": [
          {"$ref": "#/components/schemas/reportexample1"},
          {"$ref": "#/components/schemas/reportexample2"}
        ]
      },
      "examples": {
        "reportexample1": {
          "summary": "reportexample1",
          "value": {
            // Provide the actual example value for reportexample1 here
            "property1": "value1",
            "property2": "value2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


Thanks for the answer. As I wrote, it works with "value". But I would like to do "Right" with "$ref" and keep the example in 1 place only.
